# How do I create a page with 4 quadrants, each one fit into a full screen?

Tags: css, background

The idea is to make four quadrants, each one filling an entire screen. They will always be displayed like that:
Quadrant 1  |  Quadrant 2 
Quadrant 3  |  Quadrant 4

I tried one css based on another answer here but couldn't figure it out. Thanks everyone in advance.

Here is a link for the piece that doesn't work: http://codepen.io/supertiroles/pen/GpyRpQ

And here is the css and html:

```css
.tl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  background: red;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.tr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  background: blue;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.bl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: yellow;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 10px 0 0;
}
.br {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="tl"></div>
  <div class="tr"></div>
  <div class="bl"></div>
  <div class="br"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks to be working fine to me.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The posted code and that linked to are not the same.

Comment: Sorry. Noob here again... I was working in the link and forgot that it saves automatically. Went back to the original. Tks.

Comment: You can use viewport units - http://jsfiddle.net/2hd52fpk/

Comment: @Pangloss nailed it!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with jQuery:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var fullscreen = $(window).height(); 
   $('div').css("height", fullscreen);
});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
div{
    width: 100%; //This is only for demo
}
.tl {
  background: red;
}
.tr {
  
  background: blue;
}
.bl {
  
  background: yellow;
}
.br {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tl"></div>
<div class="tr"></div>
<div class="bl"></div>
<div class="br"></div>
```

Comment: Is this now ok for you?

Comment: Each color must fill the entire screen. I don't know if I made it very clear I guess...

Comment: Look at the time ;) but it doesn't matter the important think is that you have your answer and maybe close the question

Answer (score 0):

@Pangloss answered and @Mario Kurzweil helped a lot!

The solution, as Pangloss said, is to use viewport units:
html

```
<div class="tl"></div>
<div class="tr"></div>
<div class="bl"></div>
<div class="br"></div>
```

css

```
body {
    width: 200vw;
    height: 200vh;
    margin: 0;
}
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
}
.tl {
    background: red;
}
.tr {
    background: green;
}
.bl {
    background: blue;
}
.br {
    background: yellow;
}
```